# Laravel mail blade passing a variable

Tags: laravel

I need to pass some variables to my sending email.

Here is my code:

```
  $data = [
  'first' => $request->first,
  'last' => $request->last,
  'business_org' => $request->business_org,
  'instagram' => $request->instagram,
  'email' => $request->email,
  'phone' => $request->phone,
  'unique' => $request->unique,
  'purchased' => $request->products_purchased,
  'city' => $request->city,
  'state' => $request->state,
  'filename' => $fileName
];

  // send email with details
    Mail::send('emails.justshoot', $data, function($message) {
      $message->from('us@something.com', 'Just Shoot Upload');

      $message->to('myemail@gmail.com')->cc('myemail@gmail.com');
    });
```

I then attempt to access the variable so I can display it in my email.
emails.justshoot.blade.php

`{{$data}}` gives an error.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are totally fine with what you are doing, but the second param is the data to pass to the view, and as with the `with([])` method to call the view, the array passed will generate an object for each entry, and so with what you are doing you are generating `$first, $last, $business_org` and the `$data` is just the name of the array, so it isn't been passed as element to the view: if you want this, you should pass `[$data]` to the mail send :

```php
$data = [
  'first' => $request->first,
  'last' => $request->last,
  'business_org' => $request->business_org,
  'instagram' => $request->instagram,
  'email' => $request->email,
  'phone' => $request->phone,
  'unique' => $request->unique,
  'purchased' => $request->products_purchased,
  'city' => $request->city,
  'state' => $request->state,
  'filename' => $fileName
];

  // send email with details
    Mail::send('emails.justshoot', [$data], function($message) {
      $message->from('us@something.com', 'Just Shoot Upload');

      $message->to('myemail@gmail.com')->cc('myemail@gmail.com');
    });
```

and then in the view you can do `{{$data}}`

TIPS: You should create a mail with php artisan and then you are able to do whatever you want, in a more elegant way